# Sending Email in Google Glass

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to send a email to a (at this moment) hardcoded email adress when a streaming link is generated. I tried using the piece of code that was accepted as awnser [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

However I'm getting a error saying:

> No provider for smtp

does anyone have a clue on what could be causing this?
I dragged the needed .jar files into my libs folder. In my gradle.build file I added them to be compiled

```
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
```

In my settings.gradle file I added

```
include ':libs:activation.jar'
include ':libs:additionnal.jar'
include ':libs:mail.jar'
```

My manifest looks like this when it comes to permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

has anyone experienced this problem before? Is there a fix for this or a different way for me to send a email from my code.

Hope someone is able to help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.
I was using the jar files that where linked in the awnser. However it seems that mail.jar file is outdated or just not working properly.

I downloaded the following mail.jar

[JavaMail API 1.4.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.7-oth-JPR)

Then I replaced my current mail.jar file with the one found in the zip file.
I ran the code again and got a message saying

> Please log in via your web browser and then try again.

I then went to my google [security settings](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and "Access for less secure apps" was on.

I ran my code again and voila I got a mail in my inbox.

I hope other people with the similair problem find use in this.

Comment: JavaMail 1.4.7 is pretty old.  The current version is [JavaMail 1.5.2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: @BillShannon I didnt see it on the oracle page so that's why I didnt grab it. Didn't look further then that really cause it worked. But I just tested the 1.5.2 one you linked and with that it still works great